# Support for signing tags and verifying signatures in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-sign

Can't find any reference to the possibility to sign tags/verify signatures in Azure DevOps. Seems like you have to implement it yourself if you want to use it in Azure DevOps Pipelines. Am I missing something? Are there any plans in Azure DevOps to natively support this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Still not possible :
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/1381#issuecomment-537725004

The user voice for the request

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/show-whether-commits-are-verified-with-gpg-key-on/383281

Comment: Ofcourse something has to go terribly wrong first before they support this...